# appengine-mapreduce on Datastore: memory problems

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce, google-cloud-datastore

I am currently working with two Datastore entities, `Filing` and `Document`. A `Filing` can have multiple `Documents`:

- Filing - 8 million entities
- Document - 35 million entities, they might be quite big, but always under 1 Mb.

Currently our users can lookup `Filings` but while adding the data I noticed that there was a problem with some of the `Document` entities - the `KeyProperty` on the `Filings` is missing (problems with the parser).

Since my documents have an individual ID that is of the format `FilingID_documentNumber` I decided to use appengine-mapreduce to add the missing `KeyProperty` pointing to the `Filing` so I can get all `Documents` for a given `Filing`.

So I created the following MapReduce job:

```
@ndb.toplevel

def map_callback(ed):
    gc.collect()
    try:
        if(ed.filing is None):
            ed.filing = ndb.Key("Filing", ed.key.id().split("_")[0])
            yield op.db.Put(ed)
            yield op.counters.Increment("n_documents_fixed")
    except:
        yield op.counters.Increment("saving_error")


class FixDocs(base_handler.PipelineBase):
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ run """
        mapper_params = {
            "input_reader": {
                "entity_kind": "datamodels.Document",
                "batch_size": 10, #default is 50
            }
        }
        yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapperPipeline(
            "Fix Documents",

        handler_spec="search.mappers.fix_documents.map_callback",

        input_reader_spec="mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader",
            params=mapper_params,
            shards=128)
```

My problem is that I am currently not able to run this mapper as I am running in a lot of memory errors. In the logs I notice a lot of the shards getting the following error:

> Exceeded soft private memory limit of 128 MB with 154 MB after
>   servicing 2 requests total While handling this request, the process
>   that handled this request was found to be using too much memory and
>   was terminated. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for
>   the next request to your application. If you see this message
>   frequently, you may have a memory leak in your application.

I tried:

- to add `@ndb.toplevel` on the mapper
- to reduce the `batch_size` as the default value is 50 and I thought that maybe the documents could get considerably big (one of their fields is a `BlobProperty(compressed=True, indexed=False)`

But neither modification seemed to improve the execution of the job.

Does anyone have an idea of how this could be improved? Also I read that Dataflow might be suited for this, does anyone have an experience using Dataflow to update Datastore?

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that your app uses either an `F1` (default for automatic scaling) or a `B1` [instance class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes), which have a 128M memory limit.

One thing you could try would be to configure an instance class with more memory (which also happens to be faster as well) in your `app.yaml` file. See also the `instance_class` row in the [Syntax](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#syntax) table.

Side note: when I bumped my instance class higher for the same reason I also noticed that the `gc.collect()` calls I had in my code started to be visibly effective. Not entirely sure why, I suspect because of the faster instance and the higher memory limit gave it enough time to kick in before the instance being killed. This should help as well.